# Debian - error while loading shared libraries

Tags: debian, debian-squeeze, lsb

i have an problem with script DocToText from Silvercoders.com on my 64bit Debian Squeeze. It works properly on another 32bit machine, but on this i have still problem with some .so module.

```
# file /bin/bash
/bin/bash: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, stripped
```

if i run doctotext.sh it`s return an error:

```
./doctotext: error while loading shared libraries: libgsf-1.so.114: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

please, can you help?

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the `libgsf` package?

```
apt-get install libgsf-1-dev
```

Comment: No, but it return still same error message with libgsf-1-dev package. 
BTW it return some errors during package installation too http://justpaste.it/1l26

Comment: Installing libgsf-1-dev didn't install the right lib, try installing libgsf-1-114 instead.

Comment: I had already installed package libgsf-1-114 before. File libgsf-1.so.114 which is mentioned in error message is properly placed in /usr/lib/, but it return still same error.

Comment: The apt-get error is because your system is low on memory. What does `ldd doctotext` return?

Comment: http://justpaste.it/1l4e

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to enter doctotext directory and execute ./doctotext.sh instead of ./doctotext. This will add doctotext directory to LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Your ldd output shows that wv2 library is missing, but it should be in doctotext directory.

In addition you can find 64-bit version here:
http://silvercoders.com/download/doctotext-20130406-x86_64-linux.tar.bz2
This is a snapshot, but next stable version (0.15.0) will probably have official 64-bit binary as well.